# Integrating Phonegap and Sencha Touch in Android project using eclipse

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch

I am trying to integrate sencha touch in phonegap android project. i have referred in many of the websites. Is it necessary to add only the js and css files? or we should add the entire sencha ouch folder in the android project? can anyone guide me with clear steps?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. 
While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, 
they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. 
A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, 
example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). 
The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: thanks for your reply. :) i apologise that i was not clear about my quesion explanation. i am not in need of any code demonstration. but the steps to guide me. i have already setup with phonegap in eclipse android project. it works fine for me. but my doubt is where i shud include sencha files? in some websites it is said that only sencha-touch-all.js and sencha-touch.css files are needed to be added. in few links, they have mentioned to add the entire sencha folder in libs folder. i dnt knw where exactly i shud add the files and what files i shud add.

Comment: Even if any other questions are answered regarding this, please let me know.